# Can I split a large amp 240 circuit into two lower amp 240 circuits?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I just bought a house.  It has a double oven unit installed on a 50 amp 240V circuit.  I need to replace this unit with two separate units, one 30 amp, 240V and the other 20 amp, 240V.  Can I split the existing circuit in the kitchen to create the two circuits?

Comment: Is the double oven the only appliance on this circuit?

Comment: Is the current 50A circuit an obsolete three-wire (NEMA-10) or modern four-wire (NEMA-14)?

Comment: What are the appliances you will be powering? It matters.  Nate Strickland is asking if your supply cable has both a neutral and a ground wire.

Comment: What geographical location? Laws and standards may make a difference as to what you are permitted to do.